# Create react app set environment variables after ejection

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, create-react-app

After ejecting create-react-app, how is it possible to use environment variables inside the code?
I've tried using the dotenv npm package and it works, but the problem is that all JavaScript files from the package reside in the src/ folder and they sort of can not reach the .env file that resides at the root of the project.
Maybe the solution is in the webpack config file...

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for can be achieved with the [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) package. Install the package, then add the following code snippet to **webpack.config.js**:

```
// webpack.config.js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv()
    ]
    ...
};
```

Define your create-react-app environment variables in a `.env` file in the root folder of your app. You will then be able to call the variables using the syntax:

```
process.env.ENV_VARIABLE
```